Formula in Excel that adds up numbers in a column (F) if columns A and B match criteria
I'm stuck on writing this formula.
Basically, I'm trying to add up the number of total absences that a student would have by hour.
So if the student (A) is in hour 6 (B), their absences (C) are divided up into "Unexcused" or "Absent Parent Contact."  Both of these items count as an absence, and the number of total days missed for each type of absence is listed in column (F).
So, I'm trying to write a formula that will determine if JOHN DOE (A) has missed 3 days and then 2 days (F) in hour 6 (B), it will show me that the total is 5 days...as shown by example in column K.  I would then write a similar formula for hours, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.
You can see some sample data below:

I wrote a formula that will COUNT the number of times they are absent in hour 6 (as shown in column I)
=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$1801,B3,$A$3:$A$1801,A3,$B$3:$B$1801,"6")

I just can't figure out how to add the two numbers together in F to this formula.
The only extra issue would be that it would have to start over with the next student in the list.  So it should then be able to show that SUE SMITH had 4 absences in hour 6, as demonstrated in column K.
I thought I might be on the track with a sumifs formula.  This is the formula I've tried in column J, but I only get a 0.
=SUMIFS($F$3:$F$1801,$B$3:$B$1801,B3,$A$3:$A$1801,A3) + SUMIFS($F$3:$F$1801,$B$3:$B$1801,"6")

There may be an easier way to do this, but I'm sort of stuck on one way of thinking and can't figure it out, I'd appreciate any help.

It looks like the content of column B (and maybe some other columns) may be numbers saved as text. Consider changing the format to numbers and your formulas should work OK

Which version of excel are you using?

Yes, they were showing as text, when I switched them to numbers, the formula worked as expected.  Thank you for the assistance!
